# From C# to Apache Tika 1.14 Server - Error 500 using Multipart for large files > 40 MB

Tags: c#, apache, multipartform-data, apache-tika, server-error

My requirement is: I have .NET dll which will accept a file name. The .NET dll will invoke tika server and will pass on the file as stream and should get back metadata and custom parsing will be done with required format (Json to string).
Tika server is running and I verified that it is running by opening http://localhost:9998 URL.
For all types of files upto 40 MB (from types of files I had tested) it is working fine. When I try passing a file (TIF) of size 42 MB I get the below error from Tika server.

- message {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
  {
  Connection: close
  Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)
  }}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

  ```
  ReasonPhrase    "Server Error"
  ```
- RequestMessage  {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:9998/meta/form', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent, Headers:
  {
  Accept: application/json
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="a9e2fe05-bf74-42d1-b9d1-b312ea0e6af5"
  Content-Length: 51847981
  }}  System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage

Below is the code I used

```
    private string ExtractMetadata(string fileName)
    {    
        const string RequestUri = "meta/form";
        const string JSONType = "application/json";
        var file = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(JSONType));
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(file)));
                using (var message = client.PostAsync(RequestUri, content).Result)
                {
                    return message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

All the links from Google search points to Tika documentation which doesn't give any example on what the issue with using bigger file is or how to use multi part. Here I have used multipart and it is working for files with lesser size. Only for bigger files I am getting the above error.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using Multipart at all? Why not just POST / PUT the file directly?

Comment: First I used just streamcontent and sent the file directly in single shot. It didn't work for large files. So as per their documentation I used multi part. Even then it is not working.

Comment: I ran the Tika Server manually from cmd using command: java -jar tika-server-1.14.jar
This executes the server and goes to listening mode in command prompt
After this I ran my .NET application and now it called the URL by passing the large TIF file. Now I got the same Server Error in .NET. But in command prompt I get entire java exception. It says "at com.drew.imaging.tiff.TiffReader.processIfd(TiffReader.java:244)"